# How to estimate gas in an address with no ETH at all

Tags: erc-20, gas-estimate

Say I have received an ERC20 token in my address. Such address has no ETH and no other tokens except the one I just received. If I try to estimate the gas cost of sending the token from that address, the mocked transaction fails because there's not enough gas to run the simulation.

I need the gas estimation in order to know approximately how much ETH I have to send from another address in order to collect the ERC20 funds, but I cannot run the estimation because I have no ETH... so it's a cyclic problem.

Any known solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the ERC20 token address?

Comment: DAI, for instance: https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f

Actually it doesn't really matter, this question could be applicable to any function one would like to estimate.

Comment: Yes it does, because different tokens may implement different `transfer` functions with different gas costs.

Comment: And AFAIK, you don't need ether in order to run `estimateGas`. Most likely, the function that you are trying to estimate requires some condition which doesn't hold for your given input.

Comment: Regardless of the token's `transfer` function it will have a gas cost strictly greater than zero, so the simulation will fail in all cases since the address I'm running the simulation from has zero ETH. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Not AFAIK. See the comment above.

Comment: If you provide the token address and your account address, then we can run `estimateGas` and see what's going on.

Comment: It's true... it was failing because I tried to estimate the gas cost right after receiving the funds, and not waiting a single block, so the simulation crashed because I had no funds yet. Thanks a lot! If you post the answer I'll gladly accept it as valid.

Comment: By "receiving the funds", do you mean, receiving the tokens? The term *fund* usually stands for *ether*.

Comment: Yes, I meant ERC20 tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ether in order to run `estimateGas`.

The only reason for `estimateGas` to revert is if the function which is being estimated reverts.

In other words, the function that you are trying to estimate gas for (function `transfer` I assume), requires some condition which doesn't hold for the input that you are passing to it when you execute the transaction).